# Dependency Order of Circular Dependent tables

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, circular-dependency

I need to find the dependency hierarchy of the tables in my database. For that I used 'sp_msdependency', which is a system stored procedure. Since some of my tables are circularly depended, I'm not able to get the correct hierarchy or order. Is there any way to crack this issue so that I get the correct dependency order?

Comment: http://sev17.com/2010/08/07/sql-server-object-dependency-viewer-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

```
To view the objects on which a table depends

SELECT * FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Stock.BookDetails'); 


To view the objects that depend on a table

SELECT * FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Sales.POBooks');
```